# How to use LibSVM in Java?

Tags: java, android, machine-learning, libsvm, rssi

I am trying to implement an indoor location tracking system using bluetooth dongles. The idea is to walk around with an android device and calculate your location in a room based on the signal strengths of bluetooth dongles placed around the room. 
In order to do this I have decided to use machine learning to approximate, as closely as possible, the RSSI as a distance, meters for example. 
I have been told by a lecturer in my college that LibSVM is what I'm looking for so I've been doing some reading. 
I had a look at this [tutorial](http://lekshmideepu.blogspot.ie/2012/02/libsvm-tutorial.html) and can't seem to get my head around the data that's needed to train the system.
The data that I will have is:

- the locations of each dongle (along with a mac address) saved in a database, x and y coordinates
- the Received Signal Strength Indicator (RSSI) of the dongles nearest to my android device
- the mac addresses will be used to query the database for certain dongles

I understand the data has to be in SVM format but I'm a bit unsure of what it should be in terms of input data and output data. The example below, taken from the tutorial I've mentioned, shows that a man is a class and a woman is a class. So in my case would I have just one class "dongle"? And should all the values dongle reflect the values I have stored in my database?

> man voice:low figure:big income:good
>
> woman voice:high figure:slim
>   income:fare
>
> 1. Convert the feature values to its numeric representation.    Let's say, that best salary would be 5 and worst salary 1 (or no salary =
>      0), the same with other enumarated variables.
> 2. We have 2 classes, man and women . convert the classes to numeric values: man = 1, woman = -1
> 3. Save it in libsvm data format:
>
> [class/target] 1:[firstFeatureValue] 2:[secondFeatureValue] etc. ex.:
>   a women with great salary, low voice and small figure would be encoded
>   like:
>   -1 1:5 2:1.5 3:1.8
>
> In general the input file format of SVM is
>
> [label] [index1]:[value1] [index2]:[value2] ... [label]
>   [index1]:[value1] [index2]:[value2] ...

Could someone give me an example of what I should be aiming for?

This is all brand new to me so any helpful hints or tips to get me going would be great.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've implemented a WiFi fingerprinting for indoor localization, so I'm aware of some of the issues here.

First, to determine your location, are you performing fingerprinting or signal-strength trilateration (which people mistakingly call triangulation)? Trilateration is the process of intersecting multiple spheres to find a location in space. On the other hand, fingerprinting is a classification problem that resolves signals to a location with no actual distances calculated.

Trilateration is extremely difficult indoors due to wireless problems like multi-path fading. These effects will cause your signal to attenuate, which in turn will cause your distances estimates to be off.

Fingerprinting is simply a classification problem. Like trilateration, it makes the assumption that the location of dongles do not change. However, unlike trilateration, it does not use distances at all.

Trilateration has the advantage that, assuming that the distance estimates are correct (which in reality is difficult to attain), you will be able to resolve your location over a continuous (non-discrete) range. Since fingerprinting is a classification problem, it must classify to one of a fixed set of discrete locations; for example, if your Bluetooth radios are arranged along the perimeter of a room, you may end up discretizing the interior of the room into one of 3x3 possible locations.

If you are going with fingerprinting, then you will need to collect training data with feature vectors that looks like:

```
MAC_1:-87, MAC_2:-40, MAC_3:-91, class=location_A
MAC_1:-31, MAC_2:-90, MAC_3:-79, class=location_B
```

Where for each location in the room, you read the RSSI from all the available Bluetooth radios you can sense. You should take at least 10 readings for each location. For WiFi, the RSSI values are integers in units of decibels in the range of -100 to -1 (where, for example, -20 dB means you are really close to the radio).

Now, when you are trying to perform the classification, you will take a reading like:

```
MAC_1:-89, MAC_2:-71, MAC_3:-22, class=?
```

The problem is to classify those RSSI readings to one of the locations.

In my previous work, I used a Naive Bayes classifier rather than SVM because Naive Bayes accommodates missing features easily (by allowing you to give a small probability mass to the missing feature). Also, in Naive Bayes, I used a Gaussian PDF function to calculate the likelihood probability P(location | MAC_i = RSSI_i) since all the RSSI values are numbers.

Comment: I think this is what I was aiming for. So instead of getting an exact location (i.e. (x,y) coordinate, I'm dividing the room up into different areas and getting what area the persons standing in according to these RSSI values... ? I think that's what you mean. And that's what I've been advised to do after talking with some guys working in that area today.

Comment: Yes, that's a correct understanding. If you create zones in the room, you will be able to classify your location to one of the zones. But note that the number and configuration of your Bluetooth radios as well as the sizes of and distances between the zones will affect the classification accuracy.

Comment: That's exactly what I was saying to a friend earlier when I was trying to explain it. The dongles will have to be placed strategically in order to get accurate results. Thank you for your answer. Great help. Could I also ask, I am creating a small train.txt and test.txt file at the moment with just 3 dongles I have placed around the house. I have split the upstairs into 3 zones (3 different rooms). I got 10 RSSI readings for each zone for the train.txt file (total 30), and 4 RSSI readings for each zone for the test.txt file (total 12). Do I leave the label/class value empty in the test file?

Comment: The dongles will need to be placed strategically and must not be moved from the time that you collect training data to the time that you do your final test (maybe you have a demo for your class).

Comment: With regard to your latter questions, it now comes down to machine learning best practices. For both the training and test data, you need to have the ground-truth location. You can have separated training and test data sets, but since you don't have a lot of data (where a lot typically means 100s or 1000s of instances), then I recommend you apply 10-fold cross-validation, which is a common approach. A machine learning toolkit like Weka will perform the details of cross-validation for you.

Comment: I've been looking at Weka and wasn't sure if it was what I needed. 
I used this command "svm-train -v 10 train.txt model.txt" to apply 10-fold cross validation instead. Does this give the same results as using Weka?
Apologies for the continuous questions, I haven't really looked at statistics in depth before so I'm finding it quite hard to get my head around some of this, thanks for your patience

Comment: You can use any classifier to perform the location classification; I previously used Naive Bayes. One thing to look out for is that if you want to run the classification (NOT the trainer, just the classifier that applies the model) on Android, you have to port the classifier over, or you could reimplement the classifier on Android yourself. Regarding Weka, it does not have its own implementation of SVM but instead uses LibSVM, which you have to install yourself. It probably gives the same result as using LibSVM command-line tools.

Answer (score 2):

Since your output is a real number (distance) we are talking about a regression problem, not a classification problem. 
I am not clear if the value you are looking for is the closest distance to a dongle or if your 
output would be a set of distances to all dongles. That's something you need to clearify first.

There are several algorithm capable to do this but since you are asking about SVM I would scope 
this answer just to that. I am assuming that your output is just a value representing a distance, if you were
expecting to have a multidimensional output and given that SVR (support vector regression) just provide one dimension output, 
you would need to train an instance per dimension.

One of the parameters of libsvm is svm_type, since the problem is a regression problem you should use option 3 - epsilon-SVR

For kernel-type I'd suggest to consider RBF (option 2 - radial basis function)

As for your data this is a possible arrangement:

```
| dongle 1           | dongle 2           | dongle 3           | desired output
| x    | y    | RSSI | x    | y    | RSSI | x    | y    | RSSI |   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 10.0 | 11.1 | 2.3  | 0.0  | 1.1  | 0.3  | 17.0 | 19.1 | 0.3  |     10.3
| 30.0 | 17.1 | 0.3  | 10.0 | 1.1  | 0.9  | 11.0 | 9.1  | 0.2  |     18.7
```

So that would translate to (braces are just for clarity):

```
[10.3] [1]:[10.0] [2]:[11.1] [3]:[2.3] [4]:[0.0] [5]:[1.1] [6]:[0.3] [7]:[17.0] [8]:[19.1] [9]:[0.3]
[18.7] [1]:[30.0] [2]:[17.1] [3]:[0.3] [4]:[10.0] [5]:[1.1] [6]:[0.9] [7]:[11.0] [8]:[9.1] [9]:[0.2]
```

It's always advisable to scale the data between [-1, 1] or [0, 1]. 
Additionally, you can find some example data here http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/regression.html

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use SVMs to do what you are saying (calculate your location in a room...) SVMs are a supervised, binary classification algorithm. That is, if you give it some data and some positive / negative classes, it will learn a classifier that can tell you if new, unobserved data points are positive or negative. Hence, you may be able to train an SVM to tell you if a person is on one side of the room versus the other (south side/north side), but not their actual location.

It seems that what you want to do doesn't require machine learning at all. See the following posts:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration
- [Triangulation algorithm using signal strength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682776/triangulation-algorithm-using-signal-strength)
- [Wifi Triangulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009703/wifi-triangulation)
- http://www.eetimes.com/design/microwave-rf-design/4019032/Wireless-triangulation-using-RSSI-signals

**EDIT: Given your clarification, I would recommend using a [k-nearest neighbors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbor_algorithm) regression.** SVM is definitely not appropriate for what you want to do; even when using SVM for regression it only works in one dimension..

What you want to do is take as much data as possible (data = RSSI, label = distances) and embed them in a metric space, probably in the dimension of the number of dongles you have. Then, given some new data (RSSI signal strengths), find the nearest neighbors in the space and compute some sort of mean over the distances.

Comment: I'm not trying to calculate a location in a room as such, but trying to teach a system the distances given by RSSI values. This isn't so effective with triangulation/trilateration as obstacles can affect the signal strength but this won't affect the distance.

Comment: A k-NN regression seems like the way to go. I updated my post.